# Can someone explain this diff command

Tags: patches

I have this `diff` command in patch SUPPE-10336:

```
diff --git app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
index 072170d..5e8f844 100644
--- app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
+++ app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
@@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
 "First-Class Mail Large Envelope","First-Class Mail Large Envelope"
 "First-Class Mail Large Postcards","First-Class Mail Large Postcards"
 "First-Class Mail Letter","First-Class Mail Letter"
-"First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail Parcel"
+"First-Class Package Service - Retail","First-Class Package Service - Retail"
 "First-Class Mail Postcards","First-Class Mail Postcards"
 "First-Class Package International Service","First-Class Package International Service"
 "First-Class Package Service","First-Class Package Service"
```

Am I right to assume that all it does is, in `Mage_Usa.csv` file it changes the name of:

`-"First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail Parcel"`

To:

`+"First-Class Package Service - Retail","First-Class Package Service - Retail"`

Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right. It will remove line starting with minus(-) and add the new line starting with plus(+) signs

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Was just making sure that I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  It will delete this line:

```
"First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail Parcel"
```

Then add this line in its place:

```
"First-Class Package Service - Retail","First-Class Package Service - Retail"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Was just making sure that I understand it correctly.